# Child divs wont fit to parent

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my portfolio site and having trouble getting my divs to size together.

Here it is: I have one body div, inside there are two child divs.

The body div should have `max-height 100%`, `max-width: 100`% so that it doesn't exceed the browser window.

The left div contains an image which I want to scale to the parent body div (`max-height 100%`, `max-width 70%`).

The right div contains text about the image, it needs to scale to the height of the left div (there is also footer that sits at the bottom of this div).

This shouldn't be so hard, its almost working but right now my image container (left div) is not being contained to the body div.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.Info {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  /*margin-left: 78%;*/
  border-left: 1px black solid;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.InfoText p {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
div img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #888888;
}
.ImageContainer {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 70%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  position: relative
}
section.ImageContainer img {
  float: left;
  object-fit: cover;
}
#SideQuote {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.StuffInBody {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 15px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}
footer p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="StuffInBody">

  <div class="ImageContainer">
    <img class="contained" src="images/TheGMODebate copy.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="Info">
    <div class="InfoText">
      <p>ILLUSTRATION</p>
      <p>Title: <em>The GMO Debate</em>
      </p>
      <p>Media: Gouache</p>
      <div id="SideQuote">
        <p class="ClickToEnlarge">Full screen image click<a href="images/TheGMODebate copy.jpg" target="_blank"> here.</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Brooke Weiland 2015</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to make a reliable interface using floats.

It changes default behaviour and put your element outside of the flux.

You should be able to do what you want using only flex.

The property `box-sizing: border-box` also makes miracles (margin and padding easier to manage).

Also, the object-fit property is not enough supported by browsers to be used now IMHO.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit